Need help identifying a PCB-mountable version of this connector
I have searched the internet trying to even identify this. Does anyone know what it is? This is on the end of a cable but ultimately I'd like to plug a circuit board in where this goes, so a thru-hole or surface-mount version would be ideal.
Pitch is 2mm.
The only identification on the plug is this string: 3ID14






You should add a picture from another angle.

Measurements will be helpful as well.

What is connector pitch and how to measure it?

Anyways, is there a reason why you can't use a plain 2x8 2.0mm header strip without "box header" guiding mechanics?

Pitch is 2mm. And yes I can use a 2x8 2.0mm header strip. Looking for a closer match if possible though.

And yep I thought this was Amphenol too but maybe a cheap clone? Probably compatible with Amphenol though

Thank you for providing all the required information. It's a pleasure when people do.

My Identiconn utility identifies that as an Amphenol Minitek 2mm latch connector (or a knock-off thereof).

PCB Header: 98414-G06-16LF and others: https://www.digikey.com/short/77mt4zjr
Plug housing: 10073599-012LF and others: https://www.digikey.com/short/rf5r07h1


{Source: Digikey}

identifying a PCB-mountable version of this connector

Well, the male header is PCB mounted. So, yes, that's already a PCB-mountable connector. If you want both mates to be PCB mounted, the you need a board-to-board connector. This is a wire-to-board connector, and it's latched, which is something you definitively don't want in a board-to-board connector. Let me suggest the Molex Milli-Grid 2 mm as it has the same pitch, is not latched, and had PCB headers of both genders:

Male PCB header: https://www.digikey.com/short/m949wz9b
Female PCB header: https://www.digikey.com/short/tttdpwh9)

